# Windows MessageQueue trigger and rule: Batch-File doens't work on first call

Tags: windows, batch-file, triggers, msmq

I've realized today a really strange problem. I am writing a batch-file that uses the trigadm.exe to generate a rule and a trigger on a specific Windows Message Queue.

Now the creation of the trigger and the rule is not the problem, because i have tested it several times and it works. 
What i want is, to check first if the rule and the trigger is already existing. If they dont existing, then i will create them. When they are already existing, i wont do anything and exit the batch-script.

When I generate the rule and the trigger via trigadm.exe, I get always an GUID for the rule and one for the trigger. To check them later, I save these rules into textfiles. So when I check if they are existing, i just read out these GUID's from the textfiles and use the method of trigadm.exe if a rule or trigger with the specific GUID is existing. When a rule or trigger is existing, i get a message as output like: Details for the rule with the ID: b5ea975a-efd6-444a-9ae5-2a366e723980.... If a rule or trigger is not existing, i get also a message like: Failed : The specific rule doesn't exist. So I save this message also into a file and check if the contet contains the word: Details. If it contains that word, i wont create the rule or trigger.

So the main problem is; when i try to call the batch-file from the windows command prompt, it doesn't work on the first call. I have to call the batch-file about 4 times, till it works.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem here could be?

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\ruleId.txt (

    SET /p rId=<C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\ruleId.txt

    trigadm /request:GetRule /ID:%rId% > C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\msg.txt

    SET /p msg=<C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\msg.txt

    SET result=%msg:~0,7%

    IF "%result%" == "Details" (
        ECHO rule already exists > result.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); you are setting *and* reading the same variables in one parenthesised block of code...

Comment: @aschipfl Thx, now i understand why this didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wish to use delayed expansion you could just restructure your script.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\ruleId.txt GOTO :EOF
SET /P "rId=<C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\ruleId.txt"
(trigadm /request:GetRule /ID:%rId%)>C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\msg.txt
SET /P "msg=<C:\temp\WarehouseOrder\Installation\msg.txt"
IF /I "%msg:~,7%"=="Details" ECHO=rule already exists>result.txt
```

Comment: This works also. But I've decided to make a new C# solution and use the console commands from there and handle the file-reading via C#. Thank you anyway

Comment: Just because you've decided to go for a solution outside of the parameters of the question doesn't mean that the, agreed working, solution posted shouldn't be marked as correct.

Comment: sorry dude, i forgot to do that. Now i have marked it as correct.